# Dynamic Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, relationship

I'm using eloquent and trying to set up what I would best describe as a dynamic relationship.

I have a `Student` model that can be on a `Course`: PhD, Master, Bachelor, Foundation or ESL and a student can have a report specific to each course, therefore I have the following eloquent models: `PhdReport`, `MasterReport`, `BachelorReport`, `FoundationReport` or `EslReport`.

One such relationship I require is to get the latest report for the student's current course. So if the student is on the bachelor course I want to grab the `BachelorReport` model where the `date_to` attribute is the most recent. This is my implementation on the `Student` model for the relationship:

```
public function latestReport()
{
    $courseReport = ucfirst(strtolower($this->course->name)) . 'Report'; 

    return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\\' . $courseReport)->latest('date_to');
}
```

This relationship works fine when I run the following code in `php artisan tinker`:

```
// get a student
$student = App\Models\Student::first();

// student returned
=> <App\Models\Student #000000003dd8f51b00000000d869fe64> {
       course_id: 2, /* which is the master course */
       // other attributes ...
}

// get the latest report for the student's current course
$s->latestReport

// we get a MasterReport as expected
=> <App\Models\MasterReport #000000003dd8f51900000000d869fe64> {
    // attributes
}
```

However, when I run the following code:

```
$students = $this->student
    ->where('course', 2) /* for masters */
    ->where('is_active', '1')
    ->with('latestReport', /* comma separated other relationships */)
    ->get();
```

It always appears to run the code for `PhdReport`, this is shown when I check the Laravel debugbar:

```
select * from `phd_reports` 
  where `phd_reports`.`student_id` in (/* list of ids */) 
  order by `date_to` desc
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: i suspect you need [polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations). however, this approach might require *major* changes in your model.

Comment: I don't understand how that would solve the issue?

Comment: @Tezla I think you were right - for anyone interested see my post here on the laracasts forum: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/dynamic-eloquent-relationship I'll post up an answer once I have an implementation!